# How to stop html table from repeating TH in every row?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

here is my code, it takes informations from database, but how can i stop TH from repeating in every row pls help :

```
echo '<table border="0">'."\n";
$result = mysql_query("select projektet.p_id, projektet.p_emri, arqitekti.a_emri, arqitekti.a_mbiemri, llojet.ll_emri, projektet.p_marrjes, projektet.p_dorrezimit, projektet.p_cmimi from projektet,arqitekti,llojet where projektet.a_id = arqitekti.a_id and projektet.ll_id = llojet.ll_id order by p_id desc");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result) ) {
echo "<TR><TH>ID<TH>Emri Projektit<TH>Emri Arqitektit<TH>Mbiemri<TH>Lloji projektit<TH>Data Marrjes<TH>Data Dorrezimit<TH>Cmimi<TH>Opcionet";
echo "<tr><td>";
echo("$row[0]");
echo("</td><td>");
echo("$row[1]");
echo("</td><td>");
echo("$row[2]");
echo("</td><td>");
echo("$row[3]");
echo("</td><td>");
echo("$row[4]");
echo("</td><td>");
echo("$row[5]");
echo("</td><td>");
echo("$row[6]");
echo("</td><td>");
echo("$row[7]");
echo("</td><td>");
echo('<a href=projekt_edit.php?id='.($row[0]).'><img src="images/modifiko.png" /></a>  ');
echo('<a href=projekt_fshi.php?id='.($row[0]).'><img src="images/fshi.png" /></a>  ');
echo("</tr>\n");
```

and here is how it looks .. well its repeating TH and i dont want it :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/goeIu.png

Comment: Remove it from your echo? ...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no prior research nor minimal understanding of the problem being solved

Comment: in addition to the comments mentioned above , I noticed that you have some tags that are left unclosed too , check ur HTML

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show a query in table row (th)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25053044/show-a-query-in-table-row-th)

Answer (score 2):

Write this statement before While loop

```
echo "<TR><TH>ID<TH>Emri Projektit<TH>Emri Arqitektit<TH>Mbiemri<TH>Lloji projektit<TH>Data Marrjes<TH>Data Dorrezimit<TH>Cmimi<TH>Opcionet";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result) ) {
...
}
```

Comment: wow, impresive it worked thank you so so so much i appriciate it

Answer (score 0):

Write header before while loop.

```
echo "<TR><TH>ID<TH>Emri Projektit<TH>Emri Arqitektit<TH>Mbiemri<TH>Lloji projektit<TH>Data Marrjes<TH>Data Dorrezimit<TH>Cmimi<TH>Opcionet";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result) ) {
// other stuff;
}
```