# Show a query in table row (th)

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

i want this query to be shown on tables $row9, is that possible:

the query :

```
SELECT SUM(p_cmimi - p_kredi) FROM projektet
```

the tables with rows :

```
<?php
require_once "db.php";
echo '<table border="0">'."\n";
$result = mysql_query("select projektet.p_id, arqitekti.a_kompania, arqitekti.a_emri, llojet.ll_emri, projektet.p_emri, projektet.p_marrjes, projektet.p_dorrezimit, projektet.p_cmimi, projektet.p_kredi from projektet,arqitekti,llojet where projektet.a_id = arqitekti.a_id and projektet.ll_id = llojet.ll_id order by p_id desc");
echo "<TR><TH>Nr <br>Proj<TH>Kompania<TH>Emri i Bashk.<TH>Lloji<TH>Emri i Proj.<TH>Data Marrjes<TH>Data Dorrezimit<TH>Debi ($)<TH>Kredi ($)<TH>Saldo<TH>Opcionet";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result) ) {
echo "<tr><td>";
echo("$row[0]");
echo("</td><td>");
echo("$row[1]");
echo("</td><td>");
echo("$row[2]");
echo("</td><td>");
echo("$row[3]");
echo("</td><td>");
echo("$row[4]");
echo("</td><td>");
echo("$row[5]");
echo("</td><td>");
echo("$row[6]");
echo("</td><td>");
echo("$row[7]");
echo("</td><td>");
echo("$row[8]");
echo("</td><td>");
echo("$row[9]");
echo("</td><td>");
echo("$row[10]");
echo("</td><td>");
echo('<a href=projekt_edit.php?id='.($row[0]).'><img src="images/modifiko.png" /></a>  ');
echo('<a href=projekt_fshi.php?id='.($row[0]).'><img src="images/fshi.png" /></a>  ');
echo("</tr>\n");
}
?>
```

how can i put that function to row9 of the table so the result of query to be shown as TH of table.

Comment: Do the select query you want in while loop and replace the getting result with $row[9].

Comment: Ouch... 1) `echo` is a language construct, not a function, loose the brackets. 2) if all you want to echo is a variable, loose the quotes. Especially if that variable is an array: `echo("$row[10]");` should be `echo $row[10];` 3) ***Stop using the `mysql_` extension!*** it's deprecated. It has been for some time, and will be removed in the not too distant future. Switch to `PDO` or `mysqli_*` (with _i_ for _improved_) instead.

Comment: @RajivRisi yes i want to get the results of that query in $row[9] please help

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem The mysql extension was only officially deprecated in the latest version (5.5). And it will not be removed for some time to come as the PHP core team respects backwards compatibility.

Comment: @Petah: So? Does that make it OK to use for _new_ projects? I'd say no. BTW: the deprecation of this extension has been discussed [back in 2011](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). No matter when the deprecated notices were added (1.5 years ago!), the moment an extension is suggested for deprecation, you should ditch it. Especially if _better_ alternatives are available

Comment: any answers yet, please i need it

Comment: Ug...i don't think you can use `SUM` without `GROUP BY` ....at least not in this way, I was writing an answer and then I found out the query doesn't make sense.

Comment: also in your example you have selected only 9 field out of DB but yet you tried to print 11 fields in the html table, you are either not showing some code or you have minor problems with counting.

Comment: yes no problem i just realised that and deleted other 2 fields in html that i dont need, so any solutions please ?

Comment: read my comment about `SUM` , my solution was simply modify your SQL so that it replace the 9th field (or add it as 10th) but the problem is that your new SQl doesn't make sense so I couldn't merge it.

Comment: @TahirSalihu: Useless? Mind your manners... You're asking a question, less than half an hour later, you comment saying _"any answers yet, please I need it"_. That's not exactly going to make me _want_ to look into it. Worst of all though, you are expected to try a couple of things yourself, first. You clearly didn't. because about an hour after posting this question, you managed to find the answer yourself. SO is not a free code-generator. [RTFM](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and mind your language